# "ip" command of iproute2 package

Tags: command-line, terminal, osx, iproute

In Linux I can do: `ip -4 address show` or (more verbosely): `ip -family inet address show` to retrieve information on IP addressing. This command returns:

```
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN     group default
inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
   valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
3: wlan0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state UP group default qlen 1000
inet 10.0.1.65/24 brd 10.0.1.255 scope global wlan0
   valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

I'd like to retrieve the same information in OS X from a terminal, without installing additional software and without elevating user privileges. Is any one familiar with the OS X equivalent of this command?

For reference, here's the Bash Version I'm using in Mac OS X:
GNU bash, version 3.2.57(1)-release (x86_64-apple-darwin15) .

Comment: Use netstat:
`netstat -nr`

Answer (score 3):

The commands that you want are:

- `ifconfig -a inet`
- `ifconfig -a inet6`

Bonus commands:

- `arp -a`
- `ndp -a`

These are all the same as on FreeBSD and TrueOS.  (This is not universally the case for MacOS, but is the case here.)

## Further reading

- [`ifconfig`](https://developer.apple.com/legacy/library/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man8/ifconfig.8.html). Mac OS 10 Manual Pages.  Apple corporation.  2008.

Comment: This is helpful. Would you know which `ifconfig` option would allow me to query only physical interfaces so that my output corresponds (closely) to that in my initial question?