# How to view your computer's MAC address using 'ifconfig'?

Tags: ifconfig, mac-address

After substantial research I still haven't found an answer to this query, how can I modify the command 'ifconfig' to show my computer's MAC address?

Comment: Show us the output of `ifconfig` for you machine. The 'HWaddr' field will be your MAC address. Dont forget to run as root.

Comment: Or you can use `ip link` to show the MAC address.

Comment: What OS? `ifconfig` shows the `ether` or `lladdr` on both Mac OS X and OpenBSD.

Comment: as @jc__ mentioned - show us the output of `ifconfig -a`, (and `ip addr` if available) and we can help you better. MAYBE after looking at the output of this command (these commands) you will be able to answer your own question!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The command that you want on MacOS, FreeBSD, and TrueOS is:

- `ifconfig -a link`

OpenBSD's `ifconfig` doesn't have this.

## Further reading

- [`ifconfig`](https://developer.apple.com/legacy/library/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man8/ifconfig.8.html). Mac OS 10 Manual Pages.  Apple corporation.  2008.
- [`ifconfig`](https://freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=ifconfig). FreeBSD Manual Pages.  2015.
- https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/319354/5132

Answer (score 33):

First, your computer doesn't have a MAC address. Each network card has a MAC address. So if your machine has a wireless card and an Ethernet card, it'll have two MAC addresses.

On Linux, either of these commands will show you the MACs of all network cards in your machine:

```
ifconfig | grep ether
ip link
```

`ifconfig` is deprecated on Linux, so you should use `ip`.

Comment: Just as a nit, I recall at least some Sun machines that had a MAC address built into the machine, that was used on all interfaces

Comment: Is `ifconfig` still deprecated`It works like a charm.

Comment: @Timo Yes, it was deprecated 5 years ago and it is still now. `ip` is much more powerful.

Answer (score 13):

For many linux systems `ipconfig` doesn't show the mac anymore. If that is the case for you, try:

#### `ip -a link`

Comment: Note that the user does not say what kind of Unix they are using, only that they use one that has `ifconfig`.

Answer (score 5):

Instead of using `ifconfig`, you can use `ip` command.

`ip -brief link` will show following output.

```
lo               UNKNOWN        00:00:00:00:00:00 <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> 
enp1s0           DOWN           xx:6a:64:43:d5:xx <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> 
wlp2s0           UP             xx:d1:6b:f2:03:xx <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> 
docker0          UP             xx:42:33:81:52:xx <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> 
vethf34394f@if13 UP             xx:79:65:3e:e0:xx <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> 
phy0.mon         UNKNOWN        xx:d1:6b:f2:03:xx <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP>
```

Comment: Which part of this output is the MAC address?

Comment: third column...

Comment: Note that the user does not say what kind of Unix they are using, only that they use one that has `ifconfig`.

Answer (score 0):

To get direct MAC address from the interface name.

```
ifconfig eth9 | awk '/ether/ {print $2}'
```

Answer (score -1):

This worked for me:

```
dmesg | grep -oE 'mac=.*\w+' | cut -b '5-'
```

Comment: Your answer is a bit terse and could be improved by explaining the code. Note too that the user in the question does not say they are on a specific type of Unix, only one that has `ifconfig`.